# pysmb delete recursively folder sub-folder and files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a shared folder with a folder at the root with sub-folders and files.

I can not find how to recursively delete folders at the root with sub-folders and files.

May I have some help please.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

This the function by Michael for python 2.7:

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

dry_run = True  # Set to True to test if all files/folders can be "walked". Set to False to perform the deletion.
userID = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'
client_machine_name = 'testclient'   # Usually safe to use 'testclient'
server_name = 'MYSERVER'   # Must match the NetBIOS name of the remote server
server_ip = '192.168.1.10' # Must point to the correct IP address
domain_name = ''           # Safe to leave blank, or fill in the domain used for your remote server
shared_folder = 'smbtest'  # Set to the shared folder name

conn = SMBConnection(userID, password, client_machine_name, server_name, domain=domain_name, use_ntlm_v2=True, is_direct_tcp=True)
conn.connect(server_ip, 445)

def walk_path(path):
    print 'Walking path', path
    for p in conn.listPath(shared_folder, path):
        if p.filename!='.' and p.filename!='..':
            parentPath = path
            if not parentPath.endswith('/'):
                parentPath += '/'

            if p.isDirectory:
                walk_path(parentPath+p.filename)
                print 'Deleting folder (%s) in %s' % ( p.filename, path )
                if not dry_run:
                    conn.deleteDirectory('smbtest', parentPath+p.filename)
            else:
                print 'Deleting file (%s) in %s' % ( p.filename, path )
                if not dry_run:
                    conn.deleteFiles('smbtest', parentPath+p.filename)

# Start and delete everything at shared folder root
walk_path('/')
```