# copy all files in directory/subdirectories from samba with python

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, samba, smb

I'm trying to copy a whole directory or all the files in a directory and its subdirectories from a Samba (SMB) connection, using a Python script. I know how to get an individual file using:

```
conn = SMBConnection('server',
                     'password',
                     'IP',
                     'share',
                     use_ntlm_v2 = True)
assert conn.connect('IP', 139)

x = 'test.txt'

with open(x, 'wb') as fp:
    conn.retrieveFile('shared', '/EC/test/Pytest/Confocal/test.txt', fp)
```

But I would like to implement something like:

```
root = "/home/to/directory/"
path = os.path.join(root, "source")
destination = "/home/to/target/directory/"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print (os.path.join(path, name))
        if name.endswith(".nimp"):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(path, name), destination)
```

To get all files in subdirectories with a specific type (ie .nimp). This code works when using a local directory, but I cannot implement it to the SMB connection.
According to the [documentation](http://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html), there is no command to copy a whole folder. I would also like to dynamically save files as their current names in the SMB connection. Any suggestions?

Alternatively, I was thinking about copying a whole folder, and then using the second bit of code to copy all files, and then delete the copied folder after. Would that also be possible?

Also, there is no post on this site that addresses my specific question.

Comment: can't you use this to get a list of all files, --> http://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection.listPath and then use your logic to grab all of them in succession?

Comment: @aws_apprentice when I try to use that, I get a list like: `[<smb.base.SharedFile object at 0x7fb3605277b8>, <smb.base.SharedFile object at 0x7fb360527828>, <smb.base.SharedFile object at 0x7fb360527898>]`

Comment: according to the docs, each one should have the `filename` attribute to give you the long filename

Comment: @aws_apprentice I can't seem to pass those outputs as a `path` for the `retrieveFile` command. I tried using a `for` loop with the `listPath` command. Would you mind showing me an example of how I could make it work?

Comment: I am not familiar with `smb` nor do I have a server I can test this on, there's probably something in the docs? this person does what you want but instead they delete as opposed to copy, --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871317/pysmb-delete-recursively-folder-sub-folder-and-files

Comment: @aws_apprentice thanks anyways for suggestions. I will take a look and see if I can make it work

Answer (score 1):

eat chocolates's solution did not quite work for me, however I have come up with a variant that does work:

```
import pathlib
def copyDir(conn, remote_path: str, local_path: str, share_name: str) -> None:
    ''' Copy remote SMB directory recursively from `remote_path` to `local_path`'''
    contents = conn.listPath(share_name, remote_path)
    for e in contents:
        remote_file = os.path.join(remote_path, e.filename)
        local_file  = os.path.join(local_path,  e.filename)
        
        if not e.isDirectory:
            # It's a file -> Download
            pathlib.Path(local_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            with open(local_file, 'wb') as fs:
                conn.retrieveFile(share_name, remote_file, fs)
                
        elif e.filename not in ['.', '..']:
            # It's not a file -> Recurse
            copyDir(conn, remote_file, local_file, share_name)
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, I adapted this and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might help you.

I omitted some bloat, this is an example from my specific context, you should focus on `copyDir` function. That's the function the traverses a directory recursively with samba and copies it to your local machine (aka the whole directory tree will be copied just the same, existing files will be overwritten).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import json
import getpass
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

gameName = None
shareType = None
packToApply = None
basePath = None

def readUsername():
    return ''

def readPw():
    return ''

def copyPack(conn):
    os.chdir(os.path.join(HOME_DIR, config_data.get('pathToEngineFromHome', ''), f"engine/games/{gameName}"))

    for e in conn.listPath(SHARE_NAME, basePath):
        if e.isDirectory and e.filename not in ['.', '..']:
            copyDir(conn, e.filename)

def copyDir(conn, dirName):
    dir = conn.listPath(SHARE_NAME, os.path.join(basePath, dirName))
    for e in dir:
        if not e.isDirectory:
            filepath = os.path.join(dirName, e.filename)
            with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
                conn.retrieveFile(SHARE_NAME, os.path.join(basePath, filepath), f)
        elif e.filename not in ['.', '..']:
            copyDir(conn, os.path.join(dirName, e.filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if gameName and type:
        basePath = f'{gameName}/INT/{shareType}/{packToApply}/EXPORTS'

        username = readUsername()
        pw = readPw()
        
        # create samba connection
        conn = SMBConnection(username, pw, 'AIAIAI', 'SERVER', use_ntlm_v2=True)
        assert conn.connect(SHARES_SERVER)

        copyPack(conn)

        conn.close()
```